# Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in (PHP 7.4.9)

Tags: php, arrays

I not much of a coder, I can look and somewhat guess and figure out what's going on and know just enough to make myself dangerous, so please be kind.  This was given to me to work on.

I have PHP 7.4.9 installed but the PHP was originally set up in PHP 5.  In PHP 5 everything is working fine.  In 7.4.9 I am getting the error "Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in."  This page has 9 different arrays pulling from different systems using Oracle.  All the arrays work except for the first one has issues.  Some keys work and others do not.  I found that if i remove those keys it works properly.  My thought process is that PHP 5 was more forgiving and skipped over the numbers not pulling data but for each number that is not working i get the same "bool" error.

I want it to go through each key of the array, if the key is not reporting a value do nothing and move to the next key.

Errors with this Array

```php
 $L2toMES= array(
        "receive_l2" => array (1126,2126,2226,2326,4126,4226,4326,4426,5126,5226,5326)
```

No Error when numbers are removed

```
        "receive_l2" => array (1126,2226,2326,4226,4326,5226,5326)
```

The number in the array's are associated with $msgID in the code below and the error occurs 13 lines down , $Img = dangerLevel($msgID, $row['hardTime']);.

```php
foreach ($lastMessage as $tableNm=>$msgNum)  {
            foreach ($msgNum as $msgID){    
                //query and obtain the current count at status 0, and the average time in queue (in days, hours and seconds), provided those messages do not have remarks indicating a wait reason.
                //obtain the time of the most recent successful message and continue
                $row = exeQuery($conn, "SELECT to_char(max($modified), 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as \"maxModified\", to_char(to_date('00:00:00','HH24:MI:SS') + (sysdate - max($modified)), 'HH24:MI:SS') as \"timeSince\", to_char(to_date('1','J') + (sysdate - (max($modified))), 'J') - 1 as \"daySince\", ((sysdate - max($modified))*86400) as \"hardTime\" FROM MES.$tableNm WHERE (message_no = $msgID and status = 1 and $created > sysdate - 3/24 and $modified > sysdate - 3/24) group by message_no");
                
                //assess risk for the status bubbles
                $Img = dangerLevel($msgID, $row['hardTime']);
                
                printRow($msgID, $Img, $row['timeSince'], $row['daySince']);
```

Comment: The error is telling you that `$row` is a Boolean. `exeQuery` (whatever that is) is returning that Boolean. Do some debugging and find out why. No matter what DB connection library you're using (OCI8 or PDO), they are able to report query errors. Make sure you can see them

Comment: Each debug I run, i get the same message in the row $Img.  So not sure if im running it correctly.  From further testing, it seems that at some point the numbers in the array are pulling a null or empty value and showing the error.  If i remove the number the error goes away and Ive see the error on other number but go away after a time.  Is there a way to filter the array to say if null or empty do nothing and continue.  I've search and tried several options and hitting a brick wall.  Ive tried isset, array_filter, unset, and several other options.

Answer (score -1):

Found the resolution - I had to add an if(empty.. after $row = exeQuery;.  This basically told the code to continue to the next key in the array if a key did not return a value.

```
                if(empty($row)){
                {
                    continue;
                
                }

                    return $row;
                }
```